# marquee should start from the middle?

Tags: html, marquee

I am using marquee to show the dashboard on my site, the marquee tag is written as:

```
<marquee loop="infinite" behavior="scroll" direction="up" scrollamount="1" height="500" width="500">
    .............
    .............
</marquee>
```

As you can see the marquee contents are scrolling from down to up.

### Problem

> When I hit the URL from browser, the place where marquee is used look
>   empty and then the marquee content start coming from the bottom.

What I want is the marquee content should start from the middle rather than from the bottom.

Comment: The [Marquee element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element) is an awful element that should not be used anymore. Actually, it has been [deprecated by the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete). Not only is the element difficult to customize, it can also be very irritating for your visitors. If you want to scroll a text, try and use javascript to create exactly what you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<marquee>` element does not have this functionality. There are some proposals to create marquees with CSS3, but those are far from definitive.

So the only real alternative is to write one in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This stops in the middle and starts at the middle:

```
<marquee BEHAVIOR="alternate" SCROLLAMOUNT="6" DIRECTION="down">
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case. Just set the style margin-top:-500px (-height_of_marquee) of the element wrapped by marquee should work.

Answer (score -1):

if you will change the attribute height of the marqee tag to 100 or something like this it wont start  from the buttom

Comment: Well, the text still doesn't start in the middle of the marquee, it still starts at its very bottom. Even if the bottom is higher up on the screen. Which browsers did you test with?

Comment: you meen it starts in the middle of the marqee or in the middle of the page?

Answer (score -1):

So when ever you use this code

```
<marquee loop="infinite" behavior="scroll" direction="up" scrollamount="1" height="500" width="500">
    .............
    .............
</marquee>
```

for the first block add `style="margin-top:-value"` so that it will starts from the middle.